# Highchart error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: javascript, mysql, highcharts

I have the following script which I have extracted from my inspect element. I extract 2 element from mysql db which is the datetime and speed and I have format it accordingly. All looks fine as I have printed even the array content from mysql. It gives me the error at here data: `[[2014-12-13 13:23,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:23,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:24,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:24,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:25,0 ....... Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

Another thing how to enable the x-axis to show dynamic range and scale based on my data which can be few hours to few days.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
Array
(
    [0] => [2014-12-13 13:23,0 ]
    [1] => [2014-12-13 13:23,0 ]
    [2] => [2014-12-13 13:24,0 ]
    [3] => [2014-12-13 13:24,0 ]
    [4] => [2014-12-13 13:25,0 ]
    [5] => [2014-12-13 13:25,0 ]
    [6] => [2014-12-13 13:26,0 ]
    [7] => [2014-12-13 13:26,0 ]
    [8] => [2014-12-13 13:26,0 ]
    [9] => [2014-12-13 13:26,0 ]
    [10] => [2014-12-13 13:27,0 ]
    [11] => [2014-12-13 13:27,0 ]
    [12] => [2014-12-13 13:27,0 ]
    [13] => [2014-12-13 13:27,0 ]
    [14] => [2014-12-13 13:28,0 ]
    [15] => [2014-12-13 13:28,0 ]
    [16] => [2014-12-13 13:28,0 ]
    [17] => [2014-12-13 13:28,0 ]
    [18] => [2014-12-13 13:29,0 ]
    [19] => [2014-12-13 13:29,0 ]
    [20] => [2014-12-13 13:30,40 ]
    [21] => [2014-12-13 13:30,40 ]
    [22] => [2014-12-13 13:30,54 ]
    [23] => [2014-12-13 13:31,44 ]
    [24] => [2014-12-13 13:31,44 ]
    [25] => [2014-12-13 13:31,44 ]
    [26] => [2014-12-13 13:31,44 ]
    [27] => [2014-12-13 13:31,44 ]
    [28] => [2014-12-13 13:31,44 ]
    [29] => [2014-12-13 13:31,44 ]
    [30] => [2014-12-13 13:31,44 ]
    [31] => [2014-12-13 13:32,55 ]
    [32] => [2014-12-13 13:32,36 ]
    [33] => [2014-12-13 13:33,39 ]
    [34] => [2014-12-13 13:33,49 ]
    [35] => [2014-12-13 13:34,65 ]
    [36] => [2014-12-13 13:34,46 ]
    [37] => [2014-12-13 13:35,55 ]
    [38] => [2014-12-13 13:35,55 ]
    [39] => [2014-12-13 13:35,55 ]
    [40] => [2014-12-13 13:35,19 ]
    [41] => [2014-12-13 13:35,25 ]
    [42] => [2014-12-13 13:35,25 ]
    [43] => [2014-12-13 13:35,25 ]
    [44] => [2014-12-13 13:36,25 ]
    [45] => [2014-12-13 13:36,25 ]
    [46] => [2014-12-13 13:36,10 ]
    [47] => [2014-12-13 13:36,10 ]
    [48] => [2014-12-13 13:36,10 ]
    [49] => [2014-12-13 13:37,14 ]
    [50] => [2014-12-13 13:37,14 ]
    [51] => [2014-12-13 13:37,14 ]
    [52] => [2014-12-13 13:37,9 ]
    [53] => [2014-12-13 13:38,0 ]
    [54] => [2014-12-13 13:38,0 ]
    [55] => [2014-12-13 13:38,0 ]
    [56] => [2014-12-13 13:38,0 ]
    [57] => [2014-12-13 13:38,0 ]
    [58] => [2014-12-13 13:39,0 ]
    [59] => [2014-12-13 13:39,0 ]
    [60] => [2014-12-13 13:40,0 ]
    [61] => [2014-12-13 13:40,0 ]
    [62] => [2014-12-13 13:40,0 ]
    [63] => [2014-12-13 13:40,0 ]
    [64] => [2014-12-13 13:41,0 ]
    [65] => [2014-12-13 13:41,0 ]
)

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'line',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 25
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Speed Chart',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
                            second : '%H:%M',
                                            minute : '%H:%M',
                                            hour : '%H:%M',
                                            day : '%e',
                                            week : '%e',
                                            month : '%e',
                                            year : '%e'    
                        }
                    },

                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Speed (km/h)'
                        },
                        min: 0
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.x) +': '+ this.y;
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -10,
                        y: 100,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Field1',
                        data: [[2014-12-13 13:23,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:23,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:24,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:24,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:25,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:25,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:26,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:26,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:26,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:26,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:27,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:27,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:27,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:27,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:28,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:28,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:28,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:28,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:29,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:29,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:30,40 ],[2014-12-13 13:30,40 ],[2014-12-13 13:30,54 ],[2014-12-13 13:31,44 ],[2014-12-13 13:31,44 ],[2014-12-13 13:31,44 ],[2014-12-13 13:31,44 ],[2014-12-13 13:31,44 ],[2014-12-13 13:31,44 ],[2014-12-13 13:31,44 ],[2014-12-13 13:31,44 ],[2014-12-13 13:32,55 ],[2014-12-13 13:32,36 ],[2014-12-13 13:33,39 ],[2014-12-13 13:33,49 ],[2014-12-13 13:34,65 ],[2014-12-13 13:34,46 ],[2014-12-13 13:35,55 ],[2014-12-13 13:35,55 ],[2014-12-13 13:35,55 ],[2014-12-13 13:35,19 ],[2014-12-13 13:35,25 ],[2014-12-13 13:35,25 ],[2014-12-13 13:35,25 ],[2014-12-13 13:36,25 ],[2014-12-13 13:36,25 ],[2014-12-13 13:36,10 ],[2014-12-13 13:36,10 ],[2014-12-13 13:36,10 ],[2014-12-13 13:37,14 ],[2014-12-13 13:37,14 ],[2014-12-13 13:37,14 ],[2014-12-13 13:37,9 ],[2014-12-13 13:38,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:38,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:38,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:38,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:38,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:39,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:39,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:40,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:40,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:40,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:40,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:41,0 ],[2014-12-13 13:41,0 ]]

                    }]


                });
            });

        });

        </script>
<style>
```

Comment: The example I found here ... http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time ... uses `Date.UTC(1971, 2, 15)` which when executed returns a number value.  Can this date format be converted to match the numeric format they seem to be using?

Comment: My dateformat is yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm so I am not sure will that that be applicable?

Comment: I tried this for instance Date.UTC(2014-12-13 13:23),10 but its still the same error.

Comment: That may be the dateformat, but `data: [[2014-12-13 13:23,0 ], ...` is not a valid type in JavaScript; it needs to be a string, number, object of some type.  The Highchart example is converted to a number.  Your date format can be converted via JavaScript to a number, as well.

Comment: `Date.UTC(2014,12,13,13,23)` returns `1421155380000`; so you MIGHT be able to use `[1421155380000, 0]` ...

Comment: My actual line at that point is this data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>] ? In my php this how I gather all the data together  $dateTimer1 = date('Y-m-d H:i', $row['dateTimer']);
      $speed=$row['speed'];
     
      $data[] = "[$dateTimer1,$speed ]";

Comment: Could `date('Y-m-d H:i', $row['dateTimer']);` be changed to `date('Y,m,d,H,i', $row['dateTimer'])` and ... `[<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]` to `[Date.UTC(<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>)]`?

Comment: Ok I took you idea and just pass the UNIX_TIMESTAMP of my date time value and the chart is now seen. The challenge how to show the x-axis with the correct data and time value?

Comment: If use this method [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>] to [Date.UTC(<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>)] how to put the speed value?

Comment: `[Date.UTC(<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>), <?php echo $speed ?>]` or something like that ... been a while on PHP.

Comment: As to irregular intervals ... see this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time ???

Comment: I tried this method data: [Date.UTC(<?php echo $dataDate; ?>), <?php echo $dataSpeed; ?> ] where both $dataDate and $dataSpeed was the array to store both data but nothing appears now.

Comment: Looking back, it seems like you and I got some things mixed up ... try setting `$daeTime1 = ` UNIX_TIMESTAMP (as you described, and leave `$speed` as it was.  Then, use `$data` and the join as you had them before ...

Comment: Yes this works $speed=$row['speed'];      
      $data[] = "[$dateTimer1,$speed ]"; where in the series I add this data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>] . The only problem to be solve how to show the x-axis with the datetime format as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm because now its showing some numbers e.g. 10:00:48.278 , 10:00:48.378 etc.

Comment: Change ... datetimelabelformat to ONLY be `{ minute: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'}` ... Highcharts chooses the best of the list you enter to fit.  If you only want this, only enter one choice.

Comment: Going to move some to answer.

Comment: I tried to change to only one but it still with that funny number i mentioned earlier.

Comment: I'm going to have to say I'm out of my league on this particular one.  Maybe strip things down and open a new question for this one element?

Comment: Ok I will try that looks like no options left.

Comment: One more thing to try ... wait one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format needs to be generated as UTC ...

Try ...

```
$dateTime1 =
```

... should be set to UNIX_TIMESTAMP (needs to be multiplied by 1000 for this answer to be correct).

Also, leave `$speed` and `$data` alone; your PHP should be OK here.

The issue with date formatting on the x-axis might be fixed with ...

```
dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
  second: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
  minute: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
  hour: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
  day: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
  week: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
  month: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
  year: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
}
```

... since, Highcharts chooses the best of the list you enter to fit. If you only want this, try entering the format in all possible values, effectively replacing the defaults.

Working example of date time formatting with rotated text ... http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/827bfzr9/

Reference: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

Comment: I have tried with this dateTimeLabelFormats: { minute: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' } yet the data below is this kind of numbers e.g. 10:00:48.278 , 10:00:48.378 etc

Comment: It may be that the format (string part) needs added to the LIST: seconds, minutes, ... etc.

Comment: Sorry, hard to explain fast in a typed message, check the answer above.  The list of options for dateTimeLabelFormats may need to have the "defaults" set to match a single format.  Then, when it chooses a format, it only has one choice.

Comment: Yes I tried with the latest suggestion of putting all the formats yet its till the same.

Comment: Ok besides that why the x-axis label does not appear on the very first point at left and how to make the label on x-axis to be vertical ?

Comment: I just tried this on their example and it worked ... http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/827bfzr9/

Comment: Are you asking about rotating the label?  Update for rotation ... http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/827bfzr9/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67087/discussion-between-user4126382-and-rfornal).

Answer (score 0):

Just as a sharing with the rest I notice that the unix_timestamp should be multiple with 1000 for it to appear correctly in hightchart.